# Tesla T4 supports RTX, but does it support rendering with OptiX?

Tags: rendering

I get this message when I start Blender on a linuxOS and try to do OptiX rendering with a Python script.

```
File "/home/ubuntu/render.py", line 11, in <module>
prop.compute_device_type = 'OPTIX'
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "OPTIX" not found in ('NONE', 'CUDA', 'OPENCL')
```

Comment: What version of Blender are you running? (if it's not an official release, what's the version hash and did you compile it yourself?). That error seems to say your Blender version does not have the OptiX backend at all. Either it's too old, or was compiled without it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using blender's latest beta, 2.82. I thought that there was no problem because OptiX can be used from Blender2.81. Is addtional compilation required? What is it compiled for?

Comment: 2.82 should be fine, assuming you got it from the buildbot. If you built it yourself or got it from someone else, they may have neglected to enable optix in their build

Comment: Finally, I did it! thank you!!!!!! I did "sudo snap install blender --classic" not "git clone".